# Distributing water in containers

Tags: combinatorics

I came across [this](https://brilliant.org/community-problem/jee-combinatorics/?group=UIBnI6xDEuU0&ref_id=400770) problem on brilliant.org.

The problem goes as follows - - -

> You are given a 1 L bottle, using which you need to empty 46 L of water into 10 different containers, 6 of which can contain up to 3 L of water and the rest can contain up to 8 L of water.
>   In how many ways can this be done?
>   .
>   - *Details and Assumptions* -
>
> 1)"Ways" here means the final result, that is, the order of filling the containers with water is irrelevant
>
> 2)You cannot take water out from any of the 10  containers.
>
> 3)There are no spills.
>
> 4)You need to fill the 1 L bottle completely before emptying it into one of the 10 L containers.

Any idea on how to solve it by case analysis?

$\textbf{EDIT}$

I found that the answer is the coefficient of $x^{46}$ in $\left(\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{3} x^r \right)^6\left(\displaystyle\sum_{r=0}^{8} x^r \right)^4$, but this knowledge is of little use.

Comment: Hint: focus on the spare capacity you have.

Comment: Martigan's hint drastically reduces the number of cases. But are the containers labelled? Is putting 3 into c1 and 2 into c2 the same as putting 3 into c2 and 2 into c1?

Comment: My feeling is that there are no labels...

Comment: You have capacity $3\times6+8\times4=50 > 46$. Since, in the statement of the question, nothing prevents you from filling fraction of a container (or even with fractions of liters I mean), there are infinitely many ways.

Comment: I think it is implied that you have to use the 1L bottle completely. You want to empty 46L from perhaps a 100L reserve, and want to be sure to take 46L precisely.

Comment: @Martigan But even if you are sure you take precisely $46L$, you may empty each bottle randomly in *several* containers. It makes a huge difference to fill *and* empty whole bottles, so I find annoying to have to assume this. Especially given that the site is already giving precisions on the question. This one is lacking.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Annoying or not, it is now clear that we are meant to assume you want the number of partitions of 46 into 10 (possibly zero) parts satisfying the condition that no part exceeds 8 and six parts cannot exceed 3.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut, your argument is 100% correct. However, I think the idea is still to put increment of 1L in each bottle.

Comment: @almagest I understand what is asked, and I understand those who asked did not pay enough attention. It's not my job to fill the gaps: as stated, there are infinitely many ways, period. That's the mathematical answer to *this* question.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Nonetheless you do have the privilege of editing questions. That might be a helpful thing to do ... :)

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut It is mentioned that the 10 containers are **different**..isn't that enough?

Comment: @Martigan I was referring to the numbering issue..

Comment: @almagest I won't edit the question, since it's copied verbatim from another site. I reported the problem on this site, instead.

Comment: @Pkwssis Ah, sorry, but then it was a question to Martigan or almagest I guess ;-) I remove my comment. (I *think* you are right, taking for granted they are different is enough, but again, it's not stated).

Comment: @Martigan It is mentioned that the 10 containers are different..isn't that enough?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Sorry for the confusion..my bad

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut +1 on those comments. You were right of course. I just thought Pkwssis deserved a little indulgence. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make a tree :

Cases where the 4L are spared in the same bottle (i.e : one empty bottle) : 4 cases

Cases where the 4L are spared in two bottles : 3*(10 choose 2)
 (the 3 is because once you have chosen the two bottles, you can choose 1/3, 2/2, or 3/1)

Cases where the 4L are spared in three bottles : 3*(10 choose 3)
 (the 3 is because once you have chosen the three bottles, you can chose 1/1/2, 1/2/1, or 2/1/1)

Cases where the 4L are spared in four bottles : 10 choose 4

At the end, (10 choose 4) + 3*(10 choose 3) + 3*(10 choose 2) + 4 = 709

There are 709 possibilities.

This supposes that bottles are labeled and that each transaction if of course 1L. Please note that this is consistent with the answer given on brillant.com.

Comment: That's brilliant! Even I managed to solve it, but not as elegantly as you!

Comment: Thank you. I like combination problems.

Comment: +1 Elegant solution. Minor typo in the explanation after 10 choose 3: it should be the 3 is because ... (not the 2 is because ... )

Comment: I used a messy technique involving generating functions which even requires some computer assistance

Comment: @almagest : typo edited, thanks